# Difference between 'button.disabled = true' and 'button.value.disabled = true'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

The code sample is for Vue3 composition API to handle a signup form. The intention is to disable the button after it's pressed until the singin code(omitted) gets called only once.

Why is `submitButton.value` used vs. just the `submitButton`?

```
setup() {

const submitButton = ref<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

//Form submit function
const onSubmitLogin = (values) => {

  //Disable button
  /* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion */
  submitButton.value!.disabled = true; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried your code? what result/error do you get?

Comment: The dots connected for me with a combination of the answer from Alex and these two outputs
console.log(submitButton) & 
console.log(submitButton.value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submitButton` is [a `ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) which is an object with a single property named `value` that has the actual element.

So this:

```
submitButton.disabled = true
```

Is a type error because the ref has no property named `disabled`.

Where this:

```
submitButton.value!.disabled = true;
```

Gets the value of the ref (an `HTMLButtonElement`) and sets the `disabled` property of that button.

Read more about refs in the docs: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

---

Lastly, you can avoid having to silence that warning with something like:

```
submitButton.value && (submitButton.value.disabled = true)
```

here you only assign the property if the value exists.

Comment: Thank you!

The ref makes perfect sense now.  

I'm not comprehending this:
submitButton.value && (submitButton.value.disabled = true).  

Is it shorthand for:
if `submitButton.value`, then `submitButton.value.disabled = true`

Comment: Yes, exactly. See [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation). The right side of the `&&` is only executed if the left side is truthy.